# installation halt when i install centos on cavium thunderx

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, archlinux

The below information displays in the console. I tried some methods which i found onine, but it still did not work. Dose anyone know the reason why it happens and how to deal with it?

```
[    0.000000] [<fffffe00001d5fd0>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x88/0xa38
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000022a6f0>] new_slab+0xcc/0x440
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000022c908>] ___slab_alloc+0x2c0/0x4c0
[    0.000000] [<fffffe00002475bc>] __slab_alloc+0x48/0x58enter 
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000022d784>] __kmalloc_node+0xc8/0x304
[    0.000000] [<fffffe0000128984>] __irq_domain_add+0x74/0x168
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000107311c>] its_probe_one+0x660/0x6f8
[    0.000000] [<fffffe0001073364>] its_init+0xdc/0x294
[    0.000000] [<fffffe00010722cc>] gic_init_bases+0x204/0x308
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000107268c>] gic_of_init+0x2bc/0x3bc
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000108e678>] of_irq_init+0x1d0/0x324
[    0.000000] [<fffffe000107071c>] irqchip_init+0x14/0x38
[    0.000000] [<fffffe0001043c50>] init_IRQ+0xc/0x30
[    0.000000] [<fffffe00010408a8>] start_kernel+0x2a8/0x420
[    0.000000] [<00000000017c1000>] 0x17c1000
[    0.000000] Code: 1ac32823 b9404002 d34312a1 12000463 (f9400280)
[    0.000000] ---[ end trace f24b6c88ae00fa9a ]---
[    0.000000] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
[    0.000000] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you using? Which kernel version? What hardware platform/motherboard?

Comment: Thank you for focusing on this problem. We found the reason. The platform cavium thunderx only support it's own centos version.

Comment: fwiw, I just installed stock CentOS 7 on a ThunderX, and it boots OK without any kernel panics. I used AltArch 7 aarch64 "Disk Image" https://wiki.centos.org/Download

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Centos 7.5 on aarch64, and I was told to update the BIOS firmware or use the Kernel parameter ghes.disable=1.